# start chromium without flash plugin

Tags: chrome, browser, adobe-flash, plugin

I am using `chromium` browser with `pepperflashplugin` on Debian Wheezy.

I want to disable flash plugin completely for one user on my machine, but allow it for another user (thus I don't want to uninstall flash plugin completely).

When I go to `chrome://plugins` and disable `Adobe Flash Player` ad restart `chromium`, I can still see with `ps` that chromium is running with flash activated:

```
$ ps | grep flash
/usr/lib/chromium/chromium --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=16.0.0.305
```

It seems to me, `chrome://plugins` does not really disable it, but rather "hides" it.

**How can I start `chromium` without flash plugin?**

I would like chromium to behave as if flash plugin was not installed at all. One idea was to `chown` and `chmod` the binary `/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so` so that only root and the one user can read it (640). But that seems like a dirty hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS` to change what arguments chromium will be launched with. The default are in `/etc/chromium/default`. That's where it's getting those flash-related flags.

On the command line, the following will start chromium with no flags:

```
CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS=" " chromium
```

You can set the variable in `~/.profile` for the user who shouldn't use Flash, for example.

Two things, though: it's easily avoidable by unsetting the variable, and if you've got another "regular" Flash plugin elsewhere, Chromium will pick this one instead.

Comment: in my `/etc/chromium/default` there are `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` defined, but not `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS`. Presumably, the latter are user-specific flags. Do `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS` override `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`, or do they add?

Comment: also, I don't understand what you mean by: `if you've got another "regular" Flash plugin elsewhere, Chromium will pick this one instead`. Could you please explain what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS` overrides `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`. If you look at `/usr/bin/chromium` you'll see the following line: `# Prefer user defined CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS (fron env) over system`.

By regular Flash plugin, I mean the non-Pepper version, used by Firefox and most other browsers. If Chromium can't find the Pepper version, it will use that instead. If you're not using any other browser, you probably don't have any other Flash plugin installed, though.

Comment: Can I tell Chromium not to look for another Flash version, (ie non-Pepper) ? Where is the code that looks for the other flash? Is it also in `/usr/bin/chromium` ?

Comment: You can stop Chromium from looking for Mozilla plugins with the `--disable-plugins-discovery` flag. Or you can use the `--disable-plugins` flag, which will disable all plugins.

Comment: Looks like `CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS` is deprecated, but custom config scripts in `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations` are pretty equivalent (by setting `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`)